# get data from database to display them to a Sencha Touch mobile app

Tags: mysql, json, sencha-touch

We can fill a app Sencha Touch content access a web form against a mysql database?

In what way could make forms that fill that content is in the application, against a mysql database and once that part of this functional additions, deletions and modifications of those files against databases, would pass to another phase would consist of export of content to JSON or XML.

Thanked reference, real example of that power base it, I'm somewhat newbie, thanks!

Comment: Do you want get data from database to display them to a Sencha Touch mobile app right?

Comment: That's what I have tried asking, but I have little idea, and wanted to see if you helped me by telling me here if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Of course it's possible but there are many possibilities to do it. Please edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've "tried" to explain something better, edited question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fill fields on a Sencha Touch application, you need to communicate with a server via JSON.
The server can be a Java web application or a PHP page which is connected to the MySQL database.

See [this page](http://miamicoder.com/sencha-touch-tutorials/) for examples.